# Storing distance traveled in each state per trip in the database

Tags: mysql, database-design, architecture

I have thousands of trips and each trip has a starting point and destination. My goal is to actually store miles traveled in each state in each trip. (If I travel from Denver to SLC, to I will end up with some miles in CO and some miles in UT.

I already have a table that has start and finish points and I need to think about good architecture to storing Miles in each trip per state.

Idea #1:
- Create 1 table with trip_id and 48 columns -> 1 for each lower continental state.

Idea #2:
- Create a table with trip_id, state_id (+ additional table with locations), total_miles

Solution 1 seems to be more efficient when it comes to storing data (less rows), and I am not sure how one table would handle 2 millions trips + multiple entries per state in the new table.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea#2 sounds like a much better idea.  Let me explain some reasons.

First, your definition of "state" might change and adding/removing columns is quite cumbersome.  For instance, "DC" might be a state.  Or you might expand to Canada.  Or even bring in Alaska.  Adding new rows to a table is trivial.

Second, for simple tasks such as adding up the total miles for the trip, an simple aggregation query is much simpler than adding up 48+ columns.

Third, what about trips that might re-enter a state more than one time.  Imagine someone driving from Kalamazoo (MI) to Houghton (MI) on the upper peninsula.  They could very reasonably take the route through Chicago, passing through MI --> IN --> IL --> WI and then back to MI.